# Why does "light.castShadow = true" cause my scene to break?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to build a simple solar system with sun, earth and moon, using threejs. The system includes lighting and shadows.

My only problem is, while creating the shadow that will be cast from earth to the moon and vice-versa, my script will stop working.

Console gives me an error of "isMultiSample is not defined".

I have tried searching the web but could not find any solutions to why the error would occur.

The part causing problems:

```js
var sunLight = new THREE.PointLight(0x404040, 10, 1000000);
                sunLight.position.set(0, 0, 0);
                sunLight.castShadow = true; // This line will cause the error
```

Full code:

```
<script>
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var spaceBox, sunPivot, earthPivot, moonPivot;;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 4000000 );
            camera.position.z = 2400;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            // Surrounding space
            var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'space.jpg' );

            var skygeometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 15000, 15000, 15000 );
            var skymaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture, side : THREE.DoubleSide});


            spaceBox = new THREE.Mesh(skygeometry, skymaterial);
            scene.add(spaceBox);

            // Sun, earth and moon textures
            var sunTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('sun.jpg')
            var sunGeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(800, 32, 32);
            var sunMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: sunTexture });

            var earthTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('earth.jpg')
            var earthGeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(250, 32, 32);
            var earthMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: earthTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide });

            var moonTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('moon.jpg')
            var moonGeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(80, 32, 32);
            var moonMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: moonTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide });

            // LIGHTS
            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040,3); // soft white light
            scene.add(ambientLight);

            var sunLight = new THREE.PointLight(0x404040, 10, 1000000);
            sunLight.position.set(0, 0, 0);
            //sunLight.castShadow = true;

            sunLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
            sunLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;

            sunLight.shadow.camera.near = 500;
            sunLight.shadow.camera.far = 10000;
            sunLight.shadow.camera.fov = 30;

            scene.add(sunLight);



            // Add sun, earth and moon rotating around eachother      
            sun = new THREE.Mesh(sunGeometry, sunMaterial);
            scene.add(sun);

            earthPivot = new THREE.Object3D();                
            sun.add(earthPivot);      
            earth = new THREE.Mesh(earthGeometry, earthMaterial);
            earth.position.x = 4000;
            earth.castShadow = true; 
            earth.receiveShadow = true; 
            earthPivot.add(earth); 

            moonPivot = new THREE.Object3D();
            earth.add(moonPivot);         
            var moon = new THREE.Mesh(moonGeometry, moonMaterial);
            moon.position.x = 750;
            moon.castShadow = true;
            moon.receiveShadow = true; 
            moonPivot.add(moon);


            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
            renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

            //
            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function animate() {
            earthPivot.rotation.y += 0.002;
            moonPivot.rotation.y += 0.005;


            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            controls.update();
            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }</script>
```

Comment: It seems I'm not able to reproduce the issue with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tqs6joyf/2/

Comment: I tried using the code from the fiddle and I still get the same error. Could I be missing a library or something? All I have right now is the OrbitControls and threejs

Comment: Are you using the latest versions? Please try it with the files from the master branch: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master